Single particle state to derive quantum distributions
In An Introduction to thermal physics by Daniel V. Schroeder, while deriving distribution functions for quantum systems, Schroeder states:

The idea is to first consider a “system” consisting of one
single-particle state, rather than a particle itself. Thus the system
will consist of a particular spatial +wavefunction (and, for particles
with spin, a particular spin orientation). This idea seems strange at
first, because we normally work with wavefunctions of definite energy,
and each of these wavefunctions shares its space with all the other
wavefunctions. The “system” and the “reservoir” therefore occupy the
same physical space.

What is the meaning of "single-particle state"? Is he saying that if the full wavefunction is described by $\psi=\psi_1+\psi_2+...+\psi_n$ then any one of this $ \psi_n$ is a "single-particle state"? Also, are all these are expressed in position basis instead of energy basis?

if you have $n$ particles then the joint wave function would be $\psi(\mathbf {r_1,r_2,..,r_n})$ satisfying the Schrodinger equation with a joint  $V(\mathbf {r_1,r_2,..,r_n})$ potential. The single-particle wavefunction is some  $\phi(\mathbf {r})$ normalized function that satisfies the Schrodinger equation for some $U(\mathbf {r})$ signifying some hypothetical but "meaningful" average potential the single particle that can be any of the $n$ is sensing.

When one has a collection of identical particles, it is often useful to work in the "Fock space" where the state of the entire system is defined by the number of particles in each single-particle state. Take the quintessential example of $N$ atoms in a box. You can label your entire system state by all $N$ positions of all of the atoms, or you can break the box up into little cubes, call each cube a "position state," and label the state of the entire system by just specifying how many atoms are in each little cube. Schroeder would then call each little cube "one single-particle state" because it is one place where one particle can be, and then he would derive the average occupation (i.e., the average number of particles) in that cube depending on whether the particles were bosons, fermions, or something else.
That is the intuition you should take from thermodynamics. If you have more quantum mechanics background, you will agree that we don't typically talk solely about the position of a particle, we talk about the possible energy eigenstates and we say that the particle will be in one eigenstate, another eigenstate, a superposition of eigenstates, a mixture of eigenstates, or a mixture of superpositions. Those eigenstates aren't little cubes in a big box, they tend to be spread out wavefunctions, like possible standing waves of a guitar string that have different wavelengths that fit between the two ends. Again, for a single particle, you can ask the probability that it is in one eigenstate or another. Then if you consider $N$ such particles, you can ask how many of them, on average, are in the ground state, how many of them on average are in the first excited state, etc. This is the occupation number of the single-particle state, because the ground or first-excited state is something you found for individual particles, and now we are asking how many of the particles are in that state. If the particles are fermions, there can never be more than one particle in that exact state, but if they are bosons then they can all be in the same state.
If you want to write this in terms of wavefunctions, you need tensor products to describe how a combination of single-particle states leads to a description of a many-particle system. In the example you wrote, it would be better to say $$\psi=\psi_1\otimes \psi_2\otimes\cdots\otimes \psi_n,$$ which would mean that each of the $n$ particles is in a definite single-particle state (e.g., the $i$th particle is in state $\psi_i$). Let's say each $\psi_i$ can either be the ground state, the first-excited state, or the second-excited state, for each particle. Then the Fock space representation just counts how many of the $\psi_i$ are state 0, how many are state 1, how many are state 2, and writes the state as $|n_0,n_1,n_2\rangle$. This requires some assumption that the particles are indistinguishable, so that the only accessible knowledge is the number of particles of any type and you can't actually definitively whether it is the first particle that is in energy eigenstate 1 or the fourth particle that is in state 1, etc. It also requires more flexibility: in quantum, or statistics, we don't always definitely know the exact state, so we must allow for superpositions and mixtures of these types of states. And after all that, if you count the average number of particles that are in a given energy eigenstate (what I'm using to refer to the possible single-particle states), you will find the same answer as Schroeder's  distribution function for that state.
